# Is it possible to change the output of Lua error messages?

Tags: lua, esp8266, nodemcu, firmware

I managed to change the output of error messages by modifying the dbg_printf method. However, that method doesn't handle the following error messages:

```
lua: ?:0: attempt to call global 'log' (a nil value)
```

Which method(s) handle these types of errors?

Comment: I don't know the details of Lua on these platforms, but the Lua kernel does not output any error message. The correct way to catch errors in Lua is to use `pcall` or `lua_pcall`.

Comment: @lhf I found a function declaration called lua_cpcall. I'll try modifying it to see if that's the one.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is from the file `ldebug.c` in the function `luaG_typeerror`. But i guess you are using an older Lua Version because my message is a bit different:

```
attempt to call a nil value (global 'log')
```

You sould try to prevent the error if you can:

```
if type(log) == "function" then
   log() 
end
```

or as @lhf said use [pcall](https://www.lua.org/pil/8.4.html):

```
if pcall(log) then
    -- no errors while running 'log'
    ...
else
    -- 'log' raised an error: take appropriate actions
    ...
end
```

Comment: "you are using an older Lua Version" - correct, the NodeMCU firmware uses Lua 5.1.3.

Answer (score 0):

It should be simpler than digging into the C api.

like @lhf says:

```
if pcal(risky) then 
  print("this works")
else
  print("phooey!")
end
```

alternatively you can stop the program and get your error message like this:

```
if pcal(risky) then 
  print("this works")
else
  error("your error message here")
end
```